# Ubuntu stuck while booting

Tags: boot, dual-boot

After restarting my ubuntu is stuck on a black screen with some boot messages after restarting. I tried to use the recovery mode and use the dpgk and fsck commands, the dpgk didn't change anything and fsck wouldn't work because the system is in read/write mode.

What are my options here? I have some important files on the installation so I can't just reinstall.

Might be worth mentioning that I have a dual boot, grub menu is working fine, and that I restarted initially because I couldn't open terminals any more. Version is Ubuntu 18.04.

The last boot message is "Started the Apache HTTP server.dispatcher service .... ystem changes.pp link was shut down".

Thanks for reading, any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

`fsck` may fix your problem, but as you noticed, in Ubuntu 18.xx, the hard disk is now mounted r/w in Recovery Mode. You'll have to run `fsck` when booted to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB.

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted` and determine which /dev/sdaX is your Ubuntu EXT4 partition
- quit `gparted`
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdaX` # replacing X with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This leaves me with the following message:

There are differences between boot sector and its backup.
This is mostly harmless. Differences: (offset:original/backup)
< A list of memory locations (i think)>

1) Copy original to backup
2) Copy backup to original
3) No action

What option do you recommend i choose here?

Comment: @RoelvanderBurght  I've never seen that before. I'd FIRST make a good backup of your disk. Then I'd choose 2) Copy backup to original.

Comment: I think the reason why you have never seen this before is because i made a mistake in following your procedure. My drives are not named /dev/sdaX but /dev/nvme0n1pX, and me not being all that familiar with the Linux file system i tried to run fsck on a non existing drive (the /dev/sdaX). After i found this out i tried running the fsck on the correct drive but unfortunately it did not work. I have recovered my important files using liveusb and will just reinstall Ubuntu. Thanks for the help!